# How to get current tab URL from browser?

Tags: firefox, unix, browser, command-line

Is it possible via the command line to get the current open tab url in a browser? It can be any Mac browser. I was hoping when I find a good website I'm on I can just pop over to my shell and run a bash script to put the url in a variable so then I can do things later with it. Is this possible? If it is not possible peeking into a browser, would it be possible to start the browser via command line and then be able to access the current tab url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this helps you, but I think you can accomplish this in AppleScript along these lings:

```
property theURL : ""
tell application "Safari"
    set theURL to URL of current tab of window 1
end tell
```

Comment: Dr Drang actually made a [post](http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/2012/03/looking-forward-to-scripting/) today which may also be relevant to this. About half way down he shows how to execute a AppleScript as a python subprocess (literally using the same example as here) which could let you execute the code from a bash shell script.